# How to display XML-RPC.Net Server instance data in the UI?

Tags: wpf, xml-rpc, simplexmlrpcserver, xml-rpc.net

We've trying recently to use XML-RPC.Net library on our project.
Both server(.Net Remoting) and client have been made according to the instructions we've found on http://xml-rpc.net/.

The connection has been made, we obtain data from the server and so on.

As the title states, now, we'd like to know how to make our XML-RPC server instance, which is created after the first client call, be able to give feedback to a WPF UI.
What we'd like to accomplish is to register an event on a server property so the call could arrive to the UI thread.

We are open to any suggestions in this regard.

### Here is the code that registers the channel on server side:

```
IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
props["name"] = "SubsetHttpChannel";
props["port"] = 5678;
channel = new System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpChannel(
           props,
           null,
           new XmlRpcServerFormatterSinkProvider()
        );
ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType( typeof(SubsetServer), "subsetserver.rem", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

---

### This is the code that shows how we'd like to set the property after Server instance is created on the UI:

```
Server = new SubsetServer(); 
Server.Machine.OnChangeState += delegate(State actual, State next, Event pEvent)
        {
            uiWindowInstance.PostMessage(string.Format("Subset Server: {0} -> {1}", actual.Name, next.Name));
};
```

---

Technologies used: VS2012, WPF 4.5 and XML-RPC.NET 2.5.0

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This may be helpful: [Implementing a callback in XML-RPC or SOAP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1304280/1136211).

Comment: Clemens, I've read about. Thank you for your reply. It was instructive. However, once async callback finishes, I'm obliged to begin another call. This means that there will be a chance to miss all changes made on the server between calls. This is not satisfactory. 
Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to anyone that took the time to read it and try to answer.

I found a solution that fits me for the moment. I'd like to share it with you in the hope someone could give any hints wheter this is a solution that may generate problems in the future.

After analyzing, I found out that both server instances run in the same process. So I've created a Singleton as a property inside my Server.

I've put whatever I need inside the Singleton, so for the delegate I'd like to use in my question, the code now is:

```
Server = new SubsetServer();
Server.**singleton**.Machine.OnChangeState += delegate(State actual, State next, Event pEvent)
        {
            uiWindowInstance.PostMessage(string.Format("Subset Server: {0} -> {1}", actual.Name, next.Name));
        };
```

Hope this helps anyone else.
Please comment if you find any flaws.